D3 dendrogram filter out descendents given a number of links
I encountered this problem and struggled to figure out a solution. I'll try my best to describe it.
The problem I'm trying to solve is, given a number (you can interpret it as the number of links or number of clusters), say for example 4, then imagine drawing a line where it exactly cuts across 4 links. There are exactly 4 nodes directly connected to those 4 links, remove their child nodes. The problem is then how to correctly find those nodes.
Below are a few example to illustrate. Here is the image of the full dendrogram: 
Given 2, there is a line that cuts across exactly 2 links (red line), there are 2 direct descendents connected to it, i.e. nodes 00 and 01 (circled in orange). Everything under (to the right) of 00 and 01 are removed. 
Given 4, the 4 circled nodes remain, rest are removed.

Given 5 the 5 circled nodes remain, rest are removed.

I see that root.descendants() has information such as depth and height, but not seeing how these can be used. Any suggestions or pointers would be great! I have a fiddle with the full dendrogram , alternatively:
import * as d3 from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7/+esm"

var data = {
  id: "0",
  children: [
    {
      id: "00",
      children: [
        {
          id: "000",
        },
        {
          id: "001",
        },
      ],
      dist: 204.09,
    },
    {
      id: "01",
      children: [
        {
          id: "010",
          children: [
            {
              id: "0100",             
            },
            {
              id: "0101",             
            },
          ],
          dist: 148.59,
        },
        {
          id: "011",        
        },
      ],
      dist: 206.61,
    },
  ],
  dist: 299.78,
}

var width = 350,
  height = 350

var root = d3.hierarchy(data)

const cluster = d3
  .cluster()
  .size([width, height])
  .separation(() => 1)
cluster(root)

const max_dist = d3.max(root.descendants(), (d) => d.data.dist)
const dist_scale = width / max_dist
root.descendants().forEach((node, index) => {
  node.y = (max_dist - (node.data.dist | 0)) * dist_scale
})

var svg = d3
  .select("#full_dendro")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

svg
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(root.links())
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", (d) => {
    return `M${d.source.y},${d.source.x}V${d.target.x}H${d.target.y}`
  })
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "black")

svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", (d) => d.y)
  .attr("cy", (d) => d.x)
  .attr("r", 2)
  .attr("fill", "black")



So your algorithm is move a line from left to right based on the current drawn state of the denodrogram?  Off the top of my head, I would use line/line intersection to find the appropriate links instead of attempting to interrogate the data.

@Mark The line is my attempt to visualize the problem. The dendrogram stays the same, the algorithm is to, given a number (this number decides how many parallel dendrogram links are allowed), find and keep the nodes on those links (so remove those nodes' children).
